# Is there a combinator that applies multiple functions to a single value in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

For example, suppose I have the following functions:

```
foo :: Monad f => f a
bar :: Monad f => a -> f b
baz :: Monad f => a -> f c
qux :: Monad f => a -> f d
```

And I only want to return the result of `qux`, e.g. `g :: Monad f => f a -> f d`,
where `g` calls `bar` and `baz` for their side-effects, perhaps.

Is there a way to construct `g` without explicitly applying each function to the result of `foo`?  Somewhat similar to how `(&&&)` works, or `(<*>)` I suppose.

Comment: Calling `bar` and `baz` for their side effects? Are you sure you're talking about functors in Haskell, not about some impure language or about monads?

Comment: Functors have no notion of "sequencing". Just fmap. So you'll need a stronger typeclass, Applicative, Monad, or Arrow come to mind

Comment: In fact, even `g` is impossible to create, applying `qux` gives `f (f D)` and I'm assuming you didn't mean to use universally quantified type variables

Comment: I modified the typeclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `a` `b` `c` and `d` are in fact not supposed to be type variables and instead you meant more like

```
 data A
 data B
 data C
 data D
```

Because otherwise you're asking for a function of type `forall a b. a -> b` which is impossible to meaningfully create.

```
k = Kleisli
a &^& b = a &&& b >>> arr snd
g = runKleisli $ k bar &^& k baz &^& k quux
```

is a simple way to do this. it uses the kleisli arrow which wraps around a Monad to lift it into arrow land. I'm not aware of any nice combinators that accomplish `&^&` in a predefined way but it's pretty trivial to define.

The nice thing is that this scales trivially and is pointfree

```
 g = runKleisli $ k f &^& k f' &^& k f'' &^& k f''' ....
```

Comment: Yes, I think you're right about the quantification, thanks.  Given your solution I can now write something like: `total t = (t+) <$> readLn >>= runKleisli $ print &^& total`.

Comment: Yep, I would actually suggest the updated version as it's much more flexible since it allows all combinators associated with kleisli arrows to be used and generalizes to all arrows.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution using the `Monad` instance for `((->) r)`. This works nicely, and scales to as many function applications as neccessary.

```
g :: Monad m => m a -> m b
g foo = foo >>= bar .&. baz .&. qux
    where (.&.) = liftM2 (>>)
```

Comment: This isn't actually the asked for function

Comment: @jozefg: In which way? This function applies `bar`, `baz`, and `qux` to the result of `foo`, returning only the result of `qux`.

Comment: my mistake, the OP gives the wrong type signature for `g`, as a function from `m a -> m d`, I removed my -1 :)